# RESTful WebServices with Kohana 3 PHP

Tags: php, rest, kohana-3

Is it possible to make restful services with kohana 3 , i reviewed the source and found an abstract class `Kohana_Controller_REST`, how to use it ? If someone can post a snippet with routing as Example code, it will be very appreciated.

Also, the lack of documentation on KO3 is making me crazy, if someone knows a well documented, fast and proven PHP framework to use with an 100% javascript Frontend, just let me know, but i would like to stick with Kohana because of the powerful ORM  lib.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been very happy using [CodeIgniter REST Server](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2009/06/REST-implementation-for-CodeIgniter), which is an extension to the  [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) framework. One of the nice things about CI is the excellent documentation when compared to Kohana. Then again, Kohana is an "improved" fork of CI; for example, CI does not have an out-of-the-box ORM library.

Comment: CI seems to be nice, but it is written in php4 ?  i would like to stick with kohana , but i will try CI, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately it supports both PHP 4 and 5, so the code is not as clean as it could be. On the other hand, CI has great docs and a company behind it. So its really up to you. If you want "bleeding-edge" go with Kohaha, if you want something more... "established" (for lack of a better word) go with CI.

Comment: I believe this answer is not helpful because it's not giving specific Kohana implementation.

Comment: @GarciaWebDev - It was helpful to the OP: `if someone knows a well documented, fast and proven PHP framework to use with an 100% javascript Frontend, just let me know`. You are welcome to provide a Kohana-specific answer :)

Comment: @JustinEthier well, sorry for that, you answered half of the question. Regarding Kohana-specific implementation, sadly, there isn't a easy answer. They removed the Controller_REST from the core in v3.2 and we (community) must find/make a module for that. I'm still looking for it... Will post when having it working. Have a nice day!

Comment: @GarciaWebDev - It sounds like there is a real need, maybe someone should port CI REST Server to Kohana...

Comment: @JustinEthier - Phil Sturgeon is working on the core of the FuelPHP framework now, that has *VERY* similar code to Kohana and has a REST controller. Maybe it's easier to port that one.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the most promising module for 3.2 (current stable)

https://github.com/morgan/kohana-restify